# Redirecting to a specific page based on two location coordinates

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, geolocation

I'm try to code a PHP page where:

1. The page will verify two different coordinates. The first coordinate will be hard coded. The second coordinate will be based on the user's current location.
2. The page will verify the if the user's current location is X radius (in yards) from the hard coded location.
3. If the user's current location is X > then 300 yards from the hard coded location, redirect to this page "allow.php. If not, redirect to "denied.php".

Here is the PHP script

```
<?php

/**
 * Calculate the Haversine distance between two points on the Earth's surface
 *
 * @param float $lat1 The latitude of the first point
 * @param float $lon1 The longitude of the first point
 * @param float $lat2 The latitude of the second point
 * @param float $lon2 The longitude of the second point
 * @return float The distance between the two points, in kilometers
 */
function haversine_distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2)
{
  $radius = 6371; // Earth's radius in kilometers

  // Calculate the differences in latitude and longitude
  $delta_lat = $lat2 - $lat1;
  $delta_lon = $lon2 - $lon1;

  // Calculate the central angles between the two points
  $alpha = $delta_lat / 2;
  $beta = $delta_lon / 2;

  // Use the Haversine formula to calculate the distance
  $a = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta));
  $c = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
  $distance = 2 * $radius * $c;

  // Round the distance to four decimal places
  $distance = round($distance, 4);

  return $distance;
}

// Sample usage
$lat1 = 42.291093498546616;
$lon1 = -71.06439611612645;
$lat2 = 42.2707685745094;
$lon2 = -71.0237761587225;

$distance = haversine_distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2);
echo "The distance between ($lat1, $lon1) and ($lat2, $lon2) is $distance km.";

</php>
```

to get two coordinates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
      break;
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to piece these two scripts together to work as I needed it to. I'm new to the coding world and needed some learn lessons and tips. Please help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should post this data (the location) to the server, so you can retrieve it and calculate radius and redirect accordingly. You can submit using a form.

```js
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

  var loc = {
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude
  }

  var data = JSON.stringify(loc);
  some_form.loc = data;
  some_form.submit();

}
```

```html
<form id="some_form" action="radial-redirect.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="loc">
</form>
```

And on server:

```php
// radial-redirect.php

$data = $_REQUEST['loc'];
$obj = json_decode($data, true);

$distance = haversine_distance($lat1, $lon1, $obj["latitude"], $obj["longtitude"]);

if ($distance > 40) {
  $newURL = "this.php";
} else {
  $newURL = "that.php";
}
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```